# Analytical solution to a simple system of quadratic equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, quadratics, nonlinear-system

I'm hoping to find an analytical solution to this simple system of quadratic equation:
$$
r_{1}^{2}=\theta_{1}^{2}\left(r_{2}+r_{3}\right)\\
r_{2}^{2}=\theta_{2}^{2}\left(r_{1}+r_{3}\right)\\
r_{3}^{2}=\theta_{3}^{2}\left(r_{1}+r_{2}\right)
$$
where the $\theta_j$ are known parameters and we must solve for $r_j$. I've tried guessing some functional forms but with no luck. If we restrict the system to be two-dimensional ($\theta_3=0$) the solution can easily be computed to be
$$
r_{1} =\left(\theta_{1}\theta_{2}^{0.5}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-0.5^{2}}}\\
r_{2} =\left(\theta_{2}\theta_{1}^{0.5}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-0.5^{2}}}
$$
I haven't been able to find a way to generalize these solutions.

Anybody has any suggestions?

Edit: I should add that a solution could be found by iterating from an initial vector $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any $r_3$ that satisfies the septic 
$$ {r_{{3}}}^{7}+ \left( -2\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{4}-2\,{
\theta_{{2}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{4} \right) {r_{{3}}}^{4}-3\,{\theta_{
{1}}}^{2}{\theta_{{2}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{4}{r_{{3}}}^{3}-8\,{\theta_
{{1}}}^{2}{\theta_{{2}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{6}{r_{{3}}}^{2}+ \left( -{
\theta_{{1}}}^{4}{\theta_{{2}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{6}+{\theta_{{1}}}^{
4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{8}-{\theta_{{1}}}^{2}{\theta_{{2}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}
}^{6}-2\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{2}{\theta_{{2}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{8}+{
\theta_{{2}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{8} \right) r_{{3}}-2\,{\theta_{{1}}}^
{4}{\theta_{{2}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{8}-2\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{2}{\theta_{
{2}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{8}
=0$$
Then $r_1$ can be found in terms of $r_3$:
$$ 
\eqalign{r_1 &= \frac{a_1 r_3 + a_2 r_3^2 + a_3 r_3^3 + a_4 r_3^4 + a_5 r_3^5 + a_6 r_3^6 + a_7 r_3^7}{D}\cr
         a_1 &= {\theta_{{1}}}^{6}{\theta_{{3}}}^{6}-9\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{4}{\theta_{{2}
}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{6}+8\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{8}-9\,{
\theta_{{1}}}^{2}{\theta_{{2}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{6}-16\,{\theta_{{1}
}}^{2}{\theta_{{2}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{8}+{\theta_{{2}}}^{6}{\theta_{
{3}}}^{6}+8\,{\theta_{{2}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{8}
\cr
a_2 &= {\theta_{{1}}}^{6}{\theta_{{3}}}^{4}-4\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{4}{\theta_{{2}
}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{4}+12\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{6}-5\,{
\theta_{{1}}}^{2}{\theta_{{2}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{4}-48\,{\theta_{{1}
}}^{2}{\theta_{{2}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{6}+4\,{\theta_{{2}}}^{4}{
\theta_{{3}}}^{6}
\cr
a_3 &= -2\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{4}-28\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{2}{\theta
_{{2}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{4}-2\,{\theta_{{2}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{4}
\cr
a_4 &= -{\theta_{{1}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{2}-2\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{2}{\theta_{{2
}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{2}-16\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{4}-{
\theta_{{2}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{2}-16\,{\theta_{{2}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}
}}^{4}
\cr
a_5 &= -4\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{2}-4\,{\theta_{{2}}}^{2}{\theta_
{{3}}}^{2}
\cr
a_6 &= 2\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{2}+2\,{\theta_{{2}}}^{2}\cr
a_7& = 8\cr
D &= {\theta_{{1}}}^{6}{\theta_{{3}}}^{6}+{\theta_{{1}}}^{4}{\theta_{{2}}}^
{2}{\theta_{{3}}}^{6}+8\,{\theta_{{1}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{8}-{\theta_
{{1}}}^{2}{\theta_{{2}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{6}-{\theta_{{2}}}^{6}{
\theta_{{3}}}^{6}-8\,{\theta_{{2}}}^{4}{\theta_{{3}}}^{8}
\cr} $$
(assuming of course $D \ne 0$), and finally
$$ r_2 = \frac{r_3^2}{\theta_3^2} - r_1$$
I found this using a Groebner basis.

Comment: Thanks! That seems quite complicated. Do you know where I can find an explanation for this approach. Can it be generalized to arbitrary dimensions?

Comment: E.g. [Using Algebraic Geometry](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387207063) by Cox, Little and O'Shea.

Comment: Yes, it can be generalized, but if you think this is complicated ...